# Expressing Subset in terms of Other Subsets of the Same Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am very much a newbie, and couldn't find a straight-forward example to answer my question.

**What is the correct way to express the below:**

I have set $S$, and subset of $S$, $T = \{T_1, T_2, T_3\}$

How can I express: $T_3 =$ all elements in set $S$ that are not in $T_1$ or $T_2$?

Comment: Point of language: $T$ is not a subset of $S$ in most cases, if $T1$, $T2$ and $T3$ are subsets of $S$. I think you mean $T=\{T_1,T_2,T_3\}$ is a set of subsets of $S$.

Comment: Got it-- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of $T$ in your question, but you could write
$$T_3=\{s\in S\mid s\notin T_1\text{ and }s\notin T_2\}$$
or equivalently,
$$T_3=\{s\in S\mid s\notin T_1\cup T_2\}$$
to express the statement
$$T_3 = \text{all elements in set }S\text{ that are not in }T_1\text{ or } T_2.$$

Comment: Ok, I new is was something simple!

Comment: I am working on a set cover problem. I have a set X with |X| = 2^n-2, and 2 subsets, S & T. If 2^n-2 isn't divisible by 3, but I have to split the sets, I do so with rule with the T1 & T2, then T3 is the remaining elements.

Answer (score 2):

There are two more ways:

$$T_3 = S \setminus T_1 \setminus T_2 = S \setminus(T_1 \cup T_2)$$

or

$$T_3 = S \cap T_1^c \cap T_2^c = S \cap (T_1 \cup T_2)^c$$

where $A \setminus B$ is the set difference and $A^c$ is the complement of $A$.

Have fun ;-)

Comment: Very nice, thank you!